# runtime error : return value gets lost

Tags: c++, return, runtime-error

I'm working on this project : https://github.com/zsteve/zebra-zmachine-interpreter
which is supposed to be an interpreter for z-machine story files, but I'm still working on it.

Anyway, the error I'm having is within ztext.cpp and ZDictionary's unit test main.cpp.
zChartoDictionaryZCharString() is supposed to return a pointer to a string/array of zwords.
It is creating/calculating that array properly, but is strangely failing to return it properly...

the error occurs at line 499 of ztext.cpp :
[code]  return (outWord);[/code]
Right at this point, outWord points to an array of zwords : {15 25, 28 ab} allocated by new[]

Once it returns to line 42 in https://github.com/zsteve/zebra-zmachine-interpreter/blob/master/zdictionary/zdictionary/main.cpp ,
the returned zword* now points to {50 00, 00 00}, which shouldn't happen.

I spent an hour debugging the entire thing until I figured out that this was where it went wrong.
So my question is : what causes this problem in my program?
I suspect it's either unmatched new[]/delete[] (could this cause it?) or the std::vector objects in zChartoDictionaryZCharString().
Here is the code :

in main.cpp (/zdictionary/zdictionary/main.cpp) from line 40:

```
// error occurs here :
// at this point : tmp == {15 25 28 ab}
zword* tmp=zChartoDictionaryZCharString(tmp_);
```

in ztext.cpp (/ztext/ztext/ztext.cpp) from line 502:

```
zword* zChartoDictionaryZCharString(zword* zstring)
{
// converts a normal zchar string to a dictionary zchar string
// returns a zword* to either a 2 or 3 zword array.
    std::vector<zchar> vector1=expandZChars(zstring);
    std::vector<zchar> vector2(0);
    if(zVersion<=3){
        // for versions 1 to 3, dictionary word length is 4 bytes (6 zchars)
        int done=0;
        for(int i=0; i<vector1.size() && i<6; i++, done++)
        {
            vector2.push_back(vector1[i]);
        }
        if(done<6)
        {
            for(int i=done; i<6; i++)
            {
                vector2.push_back(5);
            }
        }
        // now we need to pack them to 2x zwords.
        zword* outData=new zword[2];
        zchar* zcharArray=new zchar[vector2.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<vector2.size(); i++) zcharArray[i]=vector2[i];
        outData[0]=endianize(packZChars(zcharArray));
        outData[1]=endianize(packZChars(zcharArray+3)|128);
        delete[] zcharArray;
        vector1.clear();
        vector2.clear();
        return outData;
    }else if(zVersion>3){
        // for versions 4 and up, dictionary word length is 6 bytes (9 zchars)
        int done=0;
        for(int i=0; i<vector1.size() && i<9; i++, done++)
        {
            vector2.push_back(vector1[i]);
        }
        if(done<9)
        {
            for(int i=done; i<9; i++)
            {
                vector2.push_back(5);
            }
        }
        // now we need to pack them to 3x zwords.
        zword* outData=new zword[3];
        zchar* zcharArray=new zchar[vector2.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<vector2.size(); i++) zcharArray[i]=vector2[i];
        outData[0]=packZChars(zcharArray);
        outData[1]=packZChars(zcharArray+3);
        outData[2]=packZChars(zcharArray+6);
        outData[2]|=128;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) outData[i]=endianize(outData[i]);
        delete[] zcharArray;
        return outData;
    }
}
```

Any help on fixing this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you add log or use gdb to print the outData's address and values in zChartoDictionaryZCharString() and main.cpp?

Comment: Actually I now have a test program giving me the exact same error here : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/113213/ seems to have something to do with returning a value within a brace and then having a std::vector destructing afterwards

Comment: I tried your test case snippet in http://pastebin.com/MDN4Qa5x, but can NOT reproduce your result, both test() and main() says the same memory location. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc version 4.6.3. What's your environment?

Comment: never mind, it was some compiler specific error, check cplusplus.com and it was fixed by returning a value outside the if block even if its never executed